# Push Rails 6 application to Docker Hub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, dockerhub

I'm trying to get my head around docker. I got it working with my Rails 6 application, it builds and runs succesful. Now I want to push the application into my docker hub repository.

I'm not quite sure how to do this, because I got 3 containers but in every tutorial I read the people just push one.

That's the output of `docker ps -a`:

[image]

That's my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file: 
      - .env
    ports: 
      - "5432"
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
        - .:/webmenue
        - bundler_gems:/bundle
        - ./docker/database.yml:/webmenue/config/database.yml
        - cache:/cache
    ports:
        - "3000:3000"
    env_file:
        - .env
    environment:
      - RAILS_ENV=development
      - WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST=webpacker
      - SPROCKETS_CACHE=/cache
    depends_on:
        - db
  webpacker:
    build: .
    command: ./bin/webpack-dev-server
    volumes:
        - .:/webmenue
    ports:
        - '3035:3035'
    environment:
        - NODE_ENV=development
        - RAILS_ENV=development
        - WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0

volumes:
    postgres:
    bundler_gems:
    cache:
```

I read about the `--link` flag, but this seems to be deprecated. 
So: Do I need to push all containers or is there a way to get them into one container?

Answer (score 0):

That is easy in short as simple as: if you have multiple images, you need to push multiple times ;)

Now the helpful answer, you have 2 images: `postgress` and your `current working directory`. Postgress is already an image you download from docker hub, so no need to push it.

As for your other 2 apps, they are currently in one docker file, so only one push is needed.

In your compose file they are both using the `build: .`, therefore they share the docker image.  Let's say you pushed it with: `docker push max-kirsch/my-cool-app:1.0.0`, you would change the docker compose file to look like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file: 
      - .env
    ports: 
      - "5432"
  web:
    image: max-kirsch/my-cool-app:1.0.0
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
        - .:/webmenue
        - bundler_gems:/bundle
        - ./docker/database.yml:/webmenue/config/database.yml
        - cache:/cache
    ports:
        - "3000:3000"
    env_file:
        - .env
    environment:
      - RAILS_ENV=development
      - WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST=webpacker
      - SPROCKETS_CACHE=/cache
    depends_on:
        - db
  webpacker:
    image: max-kirsch/my-cool-app:1.0.0
    command: ./bin/webpack-dev-server
    volumes:
        - .:/webmenue
    ports:
        - '3035:3035'
    environment:
        - NODE_ENV=development
        - RAILS_ENV=development
        - WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0

volumes:
    postgres:
    bundler_gems:
    cache:
```

I think you are confused because you have 2 apps in your compose file that shares the same docker file. And it might be that this confusing is correct. In my personal opinion, you should create them both there ow docker file where only the components are installed that you need. It is hard to be sure without seeing the docker file, but as an example, it does not look like your webpacker needs ruby installed and can start with a simple node image as the base instead of installing node in your ruby image.